# How to decompose the given function into several peaked functions like Gaussian or Lorentzian?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, applications

During applied mathematics, I am wondering how to decompose the data $[x,y]$ into several elliptic-shaped functions, namely

$$f[x,y]= H \cdot \left( 1 + \bigl( \frac{x-x_1}{a_1} \bigr)^2 + \bigl( \frac{y-y_1}{b_1} \bigr)^2 \right)^{-3/2}$$

Is there any theorems or methods about it?

or is it possible to construct an inner product space whose basis functions are Lorentzian functions (or Gaussian)? (Maybe orthonormality doesn't satisfy with classical inner product.)

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check if my edit messed up your math. Hopefully not.

Comment: There is probably a rich literature on the Gaussian case.  My first google brought up 'An Algorithm for the Decomposition of a Distribution into Gaussian Components', Biometrics vol 25 # 1 March 1969.